# pageSize works for Toolbar but not for Grid - Ext JS

Tags: extjs

I have a `store` with an `ajax` proxy that sends a query to a database based on user input.

My `pagingToolbar` reads all records returned from the JSON response, and divides them according to my `pageSize`.

However, my grid displays *all* the results, regardless of the `pageSize` defined.

I don't have the power to add any server-side Start/Limit logic, and the params `start` and `limit` don't seem to limit the results from my store.load() function. (I see all the JSON results returned in my console)

Is it possible to implement some post-processing function to *limit* the number of results displayed on each page and have it correspond to my `pagingToolbar`? My guess is to place some script in the `beforeload` listener on my `store` definition, but I've no idea how to achieve this.

Here's my grid:
[image]

A store example:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                autoLoad    : false,
                model       : model,                     
                pageSize:   5,
                proxy: {
                    type    : 'ajax',
                    url     : 'MyServlet',
                    reader: {
                        type    : 'json',
                        root    : 'mydata'
                    }
                },
                listeners   : {
                    beforeload: function(store, operation, options){
                        //set limit of each page, do so and so onClick of "next" button, etc.    
                    }
                }
});
store.load({etc.});
```

Something weird I've noticed, when I define `buffered: true` on my `store`, the pageSize works and I only see `n` number of results, although when I click next the data doesn't change and a buffered grid is not what I'm going for `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: An ajax store's paging is dependent on the results coming from the server. If you can't limit the results coming from the server, you need to use a memory proxy with paging.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you can't add server-side paging. The page is on your server, right?

Comment: It's a weird setup, I'm using a third-party App's API to pull data from it, which is pulling it's own data from a bunch of varying databases. I can modify the source code/API that builds the search query but I'm still not sure how to to throw a `limit` in there.

Comment: Most legit APIs have ways of limiting data (whether by design or necessity). Which one are you using? Is there public documentation available?

Comment: I'll check their docs and get back to you if I find anything, unfortunately it's an internal company application